# Hello World on PhoneGap Build

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to do Hello World (for Android only) at https://build.phonegap.com/apps/.

I created a directory. Named it www. Added the following index.html. Zipped it. Then uploaded it to https://build.phonegap.com/apps/ hoping to get back an .apk file.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>PG Test</title>
</head>
<body> Hello World </body>
</html>
```

Instead, all I got was this error message.

Error

```
Error - Some official plugins have to be updated if using
PhoneGap >= 4.0.0. Please upgrade the version of any
plugins that may include the following file:
FileTransfer.java - You can fix this here.
```

The "here" link in the above error message takes you [here](http://plugins.cordova.io/npm/index.html): http://plugins.cordova.io/npm/index.html. Where it says "Page not found."

## Question

> **Please supply the necessary source code for Phone Gap Build to generate an .apk file for Android.**

Comment: Did you read the instructions or take a wild guess on what you were supposed to do?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650: I read the docs and the faq. The instructions are pretty simple. Just build a web app using HTML, CSS and Javascript, then zip it up and upload it. In fact, I "successfully" used it to complete a few builds that had bugs. So I tried Hello World to debug and that's when everything broke. I couldn't even go back to my originally "successful" (buggish) builds and I just got this error. It's perplexing because I can't see that anything needs to be updated on my end because it's a completely cloud based service and I'm not using plugins. Hoping somebody else could give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW: you have not mentioned anything about your `config.xml`. At this point I am assuming you are using the one you get - without modification.

Okay. I'm going to give you the *quick fix*. But first you should know you have a large amount of errors. This quick fix will get you going, but you should read the document I've laid out more than once.

[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

**QUICK FIX** Add this to your `config.xml` for **PHONEGAP BUILD ONLY**
`<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />`

There are two large reasons you are getting these errors.

1. The plugin repository has moved to NPM. Your code shows you are not keeping up. (#11)
2. If you do NOT set the compiler version when you did your build. (#6)

From #6 on the link above:

> With the CLI version, if you do not assign a version for your platform OR in ''Phonegap Build'' if you do not set the phonegap-version in config.xml, YOU WILL GET THE LATEST VERSION. If you are lucky, your program just works as expected. If you are not lucky, you'll get a *set of cascading error*.

TO repeat, you are not lucky. You are getting the *set of cascading error* 
You should read #6, #7, #10 & #11.

Best of Luck, let me know how it is going.

Comment: Upvoted! Thank you for your answer. There is obviously a lot of information here. Do you know where one can get a complete "starter app" or set of files ready to be uploaded to PhoneGap Build that will result in a working .apk file that demonstrates some scripting behavior? Like, maybe, a form field that displays the input content after a send button is pressed? I've been looking for some type of "Hello World" or starter kit example for PhoneGap Build but have not yet been able to successfully find one.

Comment: On your request for a working demo, sadly none of my demos work any more, and I know of none - except a few boilerplate demos. The real issue for the next level of demos will be to have one (1) working Plugin and use the so-called `white-list` system. Sorry, I'll try to have one in the next few weeks. I keep several blogs, but this one is where I will post information on working demos with the new system: http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/  -- Best of Luck

Comment: Jesse, you seem to be the worlds leading expert on PhoneGap Build at the moment. At least as it relates to online Q&A fora. So please, tell me do you have any thoughts on [this related Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642118/how-to-phonegap-build-navigate-to-web-app-instead-of-index-html)?

Comment: Thanks for the complement. However, I'm also considered rude and arrogant. I'm trying. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try updating phonegap or any related programmes because one seems to be outdated. If your using any plugins like adding in your app try to see if their the latest version as well.

Comment: Thing is... the process for PhoneGap Build doesn't use PhoneGap at all best I can tell. PhoneGap Build appears to be a completely cloud-based service. That's why the error message about updating and upgrading didn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

#### Delete and restart instead of update code

My solution was to delete my existing app (instead of "update code"). Apparently, there was some "caching" of prior code that didn't get overwritten so I had to completely wipe the old .zip file and start over with a new one.

Then it worked.

#### Plugins are pulled in config.xml

After a little more tinkering, I might be starting to understand what's happening. I just downloaded the phonegap-start app from github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start and the same problem resurfaced. I think the problem is caused by the plugin source files referenced in the config.xml file. And I think these references were not deleted when I selected "update code" instead of deleting the old app and starting over. The relevant section of the config.xml file is below.

config.xml snippet

```
<!-- Core plugins -->
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
```