# How to: PhoneGap Build navigate to web app instead of index.html?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

#### Background

([Per this answer and its question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33625671/1640892)) I have a fully responsive web app hosted at `http://www.example.com` and I just want my mobile app to point the user there.

I followed this procedure:

1. `$ cordova create myProject`
2. Open `config.xml`
3. Change `index.html` to `http://www.example.com`

Now I have the following `config.xml` file.

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="http://www.example.com" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

### Problem

When I use [PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/apps) and test my .apk file, the result does not perform as expected. Instead of seeing the web page at example.com, I appear to get the original index.html file anyway!

## Question

> What am I doing wrong? How can I get this mobile app to point to my desired URL at example.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mowzer

UPDATE: 2015-11-21:
 *As of Nov 20, 2015 at 1pm PST, `<platform (...)>` is a viable element for `config.xml`.
See the Phonegap Build blog post ["config.xml gets an update - part 2 !!!!!!"](http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/11/19/config_xml_changes_part_two/)*

<s>Where are you getting this example code? I've now seen dozens of copy and they ALL have the same mistake. Namely, `platform` does NOT apply to *Phonegap Build*. The main reason is `<platform (...)>` only applies to Cordova/Phonegap SDK. (It took me along time to figure this out. [SEE](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) #1 near the bottom.</s>

In addition, the `whitelist` system is NOT being applied correctly. I'd like to find this source and get it corrected.

**Your Corrections:**

Luckily you are not too far along. Remove all the `whitelist` stuff and start here.

[HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)

Please let me know where you got this example from.

TIA
Jesse

Comment: +1 Thanks Jesse! I will pursue this approach you have outlined. I got the code by following the procedure I described. At the command line, hit `cordova create myProject`. Then open the `config.xml` file that was generated.

Comment: Okay. I and other people have been VERY CLEAR on this. *Phonegap CLI* and *Phonegap Build* are two different system. They overlap, but only if you read ALOT.  THIS IS #1 of [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

Comment: So, there should be no problem [starting with this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start), correct? https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start

Comment: There are problems with that, but you can start there. Then apply this [plugin core setup](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/plugins-core-setup.md). Also remove the stuff at the bottom that is about `<platform>`; that only applies to *Phonegap SDK*. It does not hurt *Phonegap CLI*, but causes issues with *Phonegap Build*. I need to fix it. I guess I will tonight.

Comment: Thanks, Jesse! I would appreciate that very much!